# Git. Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git

Доброго времени суток.
Почему git на команду:

```
git clone git@github.com:ReinRaus:test.git
```

выдает такую ошибку в консоль:

```
Cloning into test...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

В папке

```
~/.ssh/
```

лежит приватный ключ сгенерированный с паролем командой

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

В настройках аккаунта GitHub добавлена публичная часть ключа.
Возможно надо как-то по-особенному указывать пароль от ключа ? Потому что пароль от ключа у меня не запрашивается.
С тем же самым ключем эклипс отлично работает с репозиторием.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запустил ssh в режиме отладки:

```
ssh -v -v
```

В выводе было:

`debug1: Trying private key: /home/git/.ssh/id_rsa debug1: Trying private key: /home/git/.ssh/id_dsa debug1: No more authentication methods to try. Permission denied (publickey).`
Проблема в том, что не был сделан `ssh-add` для нового ключа.

Answer (score 2):

права на папку .ssh и файлы  в ней должны быть chmod 600.

Comment: Выставил права как Вы указали- ничего не изменилось.

Comment: запусти ssh в режиме отладки и посмоти на что ругается, ssh -v

-v      Verbose mode.  Causes ssh to print debugging messages about its
             progress.  This is helpful in debugging connection, authentica-
             tion, and configuration problems.  Multiple -v options increase
             the verbosity.  The maximum is 3.

Comment: Спасибо большое.  

В выводе было:  


    debug1: Trying private key: /home/git/.ssh/id_rsa
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/git/.ssh/id_dsa
    debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
    Permission denied (publickey).
И до меня дошло, что я не сделал:  

    ssh-add
:(