# git не позволяет подтянуть изменения с сервера

Tags: git, github, putty

Добрый день. На выделенном сервере в папке с клонированным репозиторием, после доработок на лольной копии и синхронизации репозитория выполнил команду

```
git pull
```

мне выдало такую ошибку:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Читал тут про ошибку https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/ толком ничего не понял, но по советам из статьи попытался проверить соединение с github

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

тоже

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

и проверить наличие ключа

```
ssh-add -l
```

в ответ

```
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

Причём, клон этого же репозитория в другой папке (продакшн, к боевому домену привязан), прекрасно работает на любой ветке, при команде git pull запрашивает логин и пароль и выполняет обновление ветки.

Я недавно работаю с git и с консолью тоже и не совсем понимаю чем вообще вызвана проблема. Ему не нравиться ключь, но разве он храниться не в одном месте, т.е. если бы ключ был не рабочий, то не работали бы оба клона (dev и prod) а тут "боевой" рабоатает а "разработка" отказывается. =(

Вопрос: Что делать? Как побороть ошибку **Permission denied (publickey).** ?

Comment: Попробуйте то что описано [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/271334/2110), возможно у Вас аналогичная ситуация

Comment: Ваш выделенный сервер даже не пытается организовать соединение, используя ssh-ключ (а именно этого ожидает гитхаб). Его надо сгенерировать, убедиться, что он используется, добавить его в deployment keys в настройках репы. Ваш кэп.

Comment: А команда `ssh-agent -l` в рабочей папке показывает ключ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вашему серверу нужен доступ к репозиторию только на чтение или на чтение и запись?
Если первое, то можно использовать доступ по https, а не по ssh.

> Я недавно работаю с git и с консолью тоже и не совсем понимаю чем вообще вызвана проблема. Ему не нравиться ключь, но разве он храниться не в одном месте, т.е. если бы ключ был не рабочий, то не работали бы оба клона (dev и prod) а тут "боевой" рабоатает а "разработка" отказывается. =(

Ключ не может храниться "в одном месте" - хотя бы потому что у вас два компьютера, насколько я понял. Или dev - это копия на том же самом выделенном сервере? Если у вас и правда два разных компьютера, то вам надо или скопировать свой ключ на сервер, или настроить агента для использования сервером вашего локального ключа - или же сгенерировать для сервера отдельный ключ, как и посоветовал Etki. Рекомендую последний вариант - такой ключ проще отозвать в случае чего.

Comment: Dev ветка на том же выделенном сервере. Оказалось на нём остался ключь другого пользователя который раньше администрировал сервер.

Answer (score 1):

ответ актуален для операционной системы `gnu/linux` (и, вероятно, `mac os x`).

на основании найденнной ошибки (использовался не тот ключ) дополню и ответом на (промежуточный) вопрос:

*как убедиться, что публичная часть openssh-ключа, сохранённая в учётной записи на github, соответствует какой-либо из секретных частей, доступных пользователю (и, следовательно, программе `git`)?*

ключи однозначно идентифицируются с помощью *отпечатка* (fingerprint), причём у публичной и секретной частей одного и того же ключа отпечаток совпадает.

посмотреть отпечаток (публичной части) ключа, сохранённого в учётной записи на github можно [на соответствующей странице настроек](https://github.com/settings/ssh). пример отпечатка:

```
d5:71:15:e5:e4:90:fa:9c:cc:ca:78:f4:7a:f2:87:38
```

секретные части ключей, доступные программе `git`, могут либо находиться в одном из файлов (identity, id_rsa, id_dsa, id_ecdsa, id_ed25519) в каталоге `~/.ssh`, либо быть в «ве́дении» `ssh-agent`-а.

просмотреть отпечатки секретных частей, хранящихся в каталоге `~/.ssh`, можно, например, такой командой:

```
$ for f in identity id_rsa id_dsa id_ecdsa id_ed25519; do [ -f ~/.ssh/$f ] && ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/$f; done
2048 SHA256:sNl9M36H6KH0mmjKZUtic3B1di/f9mTs/C00gNZvj84 пользователь@машина (RSA)
```

**обновление**: современные версии программы *ssh-keygen* выводят по умолчанию отпечаток, подсчитанный по алгоритму *sha256*. чтобы получить отпечаток по устаревшему алгоритму *md5*, надо добавить опцию `-E md5`:

```
$ for f in identity id_rsa id_dsa id_ecdsa id_ed25519; do [ -f ~/.ssh/$f ] && ssh-keygen -l -E md5 -f ~/.ssh/$f; done
2048 MD5:d5:71:15:e5:e4:90:fa:9c:cc:ca:78:f4:7a:f2:87:38 пользователь@машина (RSA)
```

---

просмотреть отпечатки доступных через `ssh-agent` ключей можно командой:

```
$ ssh-add -l
```