# Ошибка при добавлении нового проекта на GitHub

Tags: git, bash, github

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с решением проблемы, возможно кто-то сталкивался

Пытаюсь добавить новый C# проект на GitHub

1. Создаю на сайте новый пустой Public репозиторий
2. В Git Bash выполняю следующие команды:

   ```
   git add "путь к проекту"

   git commit -m "Test"

   git remote add origin "ссылка на репозиторий GitHub"

   git push -u origin master
   ```

После чего получаю следующую ошибку:

```
Username for 
Password for 
WARNING: You called a Git command named 'lfs', which does not exist.
Continuing under the assumption that you meant 'log'
in 0.1 seconds automatically...
fatal: ambiguous argument 'push': unknown revision or path not in the working tr
ee.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
error: failed to push some refs to ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вероятно, вы пытаетесь сделать репозиторий из имеющихся у вас файлов/каталогов и «отправить» этот репозиторий на github.

во-первых, убедитесь, что публичная часть вашего ключа закреплена за вашей учётной записью на github. см., например, этот [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417264/#422636).

далее примерный алгоритм:

```
cd <каталог, где будет располагаться ваш репозиторий>
git init # собственно создание репозитория — каталога .git
git add . # добавление всех файлов/каталогов из текущего каталога в репозиторий
git commit -m "Test"
git remote add origin "ссылка на репозиторий GitHub"
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать