# Почему до сих пор просит ввести логин и пароль при push?

Tags: git, github

Я создал **ssh** ключ,  подключил его к **github**, но при **git push** все равно требует указывать логин и пароль, хотя при тестировании ssh:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

получаю надпись такого типа:

```
  Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Что значит, что связь установлена и должно быть все нормально. Но логин и пароль при **git push** все равно просит.

**OC: Win 8.1**

---

Проверяем:
**git remote -v**

```
origin  git@github.com:name/repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:name/repo.git (push)
```

Пытаемся:
**git push origin master** и **git push origin**  и даже **git push**

```
$ git push origin master
ERROR: Permission to git@github.com:name/repo.git denied to namelocal.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

---

**git remote show origin**

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@github.com:name/repo.git
  Push  URL: git@github.com:name/repo.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

Comment: Какая операционная система?

Comment: @Мстислав Павлов Win 8.1

Comment: @Niko_D, приложите, пожалуйста, к вопросу вывод команды `git remote show origin` (если вы меняли имя remote-а с дефолтного `origin` на что-то другое, то подставьте это имя вместо `origin`).

Comment: Да-да. Не успел как раз в ту же секунду Вы написали

Comment: ставлю пять долларов, что вы делаете пуш по https (т.е. remote репозитория по умолчанию ссылается на гитхаб через https)

Comment: @Etki -проиграли 5 долларов) С самого начала и вправду так и было. Но несколько минут назад я уже сменил https на git remote set-url origin git@github.com:name/repo.git Новую информацию я уже отразил в вопросе.

Comment: @Etki хотя может до конца я вас не понял.

Comment: name в указанном урле - это ваш аккаунт, или чей-то другой?

Comment: @Etki - Не, это не аккаунт, я за место своего аккаунта вставил что бы не светить) А что нужен реальный адрес аккаунта?

Comment: @alexander barakin Готово

Comment: нет, нужно ответить, является ли скрытый аккаунт вашим, или вы пушите в чужой репозиторий

Comment: @Etki - он является моим аккаунтом

Comment: @Etki так... У меня оказывается два аккаунта было, и когда я из второго удалил SSH ключ, то уже при ssh -T git@github.com , выдает 
 Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: @Niko_D, и второй аккаунт, судя по всему, вы заменили словом `namelocal`. **мой вердикт**: либо в том аккаунте, который вы заменили словом `name`, не прописан никакой публичный ключ, либо там прописан **не тот** публичный ключ, который (по умолчанию) использует программа ssh (и, соответственно, программа git, которая вызывает программу ssh для общения с github-ом).

Comment: @alexander barakin похоже на то Но там прописал ключ я же пушил уже по http с указанием пароля

Comment: @Niko_D, может быть, [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/422636/178576) поможет определиться с «прописанными» на github ключами. *пушил уже по http с указанием пароля* — в этом случае не использовалась ни программа ssh вообще, ни ключи в частности.

Comment: @alexander barakin  - Все заработало. Что я сделал: удалил ssh с второго аккаунта , namelocal, и теперь там при ssh -T git@github.com  --- semlocal(имя самого репозитория) , потом как то обновил ssh ключ, он новый стал и добавил его в аккаунт semlocal. И все заработало.

Answer (score 1):

один и тот же публичный ключ, насколько мне известно, не имеет смысл прописывать в более чем одном аккаунте на серверах, где аутентификация происходит именно по ключу, а не по имени аккаунта.

это и github, и bitbucket, и локальные сервера, основанные на gitlab, gitolite, gitosis и тому подобном.

насколько я понимаю, на сервере вы всегда будете аутентифицироваться именно как тот аккаунт, в который вы добавили ключ **первым**. пока не удалите ключ у этого аккаунта, после чего вы, *может быть*, будете аутентифицироваться как аккаунт, созданный вторым. а *может быть* и нет (или лишь спустя какое-то время) — это уже зависит от реализации сервера.