# доступ к нескольким удаленным репозиториям по открытым ключам

Tags: git, ssh

Как создавать и подключать к своему аккаунту ssh проблем нет, а вот как это сделать для работы с несколькими удаленными репозиториями? Пока что только генерирую их заново и исправляю на гитхаб аккаунте. Подскажите правильный подход к работе сразу с несколькими репозиториями.

Каждый раз делаю по этому тутору: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/

Но чувствую что явно делаю не так.

---

дополнение из комментария:

но если у меня 2 разных репозитория на разных аккаунтах, а ключ ssh только один? Или в данном случае нужно наплодить n ключей для n аккаунтов ?

Answer (score 5):

> но если у меня 2 разных репозитория на разных аккаунтах, а ключ ssh только один? Или в данном случае нужно наплодить n ключей для n аккаунтов ?

если вы создали **несколько** учётных записей на **одном** сервере, предоставляющем доступ к git-репозиториям по ssh-ключам (сервисы типа github.com, bitbucket.org и т.п., или собственные серверы под управлением gitlab, gitorious, gitolite и т.п.), то авторизоваться на этом сервере под разными учётными записями придётся с помощью **разных** ssh-ключей.

если вы добавите один и тот же ssh-ключ разным аккаунтам на одном и том же сервере, то получите примерно то, что описано в этом ответе: [Почему до сих пор просит ввести логин и пароль при push?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/482751/178576) — авторизоваться вы будете как пользователь, которому **первым** добавите этот ключ.

---

**пример** конфигурации для двух учётных записей (`acc1` и `acc2`) на сервере *github.com*.

создать несколько ключей, которыми сможет воспользоваться программа *ssh* (она вызывается программой *git* для взаимодействия с сервером), совсем несложно. создадим два, с названиями key1 и key2:

```
$ ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/key1
...
Your identification has been saved in ~/.ssh/key1.
Your public key has been saved in ~/.ssh/key1.pub.
...
$ ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/key2
...
Your identification has been saved in ~/.ssh/key2.
Your public key has been saved in ~/.ssh/key2.pub.
...
```

программа *ssh-keygen* (в числе прочего) сообщает, где и под какими именами сохранила пары публичный/секретный ключ. каталог (в данном случае) можно выбрать и другой, просто именно там (`~/.ssh`) программа *ssh* будет разыскивать пары ключей, если не указывать полный путь к ним.

чтобы теперь обращаться к одному и тому же серверу (`github.com`) с разными ключами, надо добавить в `~/.ssh/config` две секции:

```
host gh-acc1
hostname github.com
user git
identityfile key1

host gh-acc2
hostname github.com
user git
identityfile key2
```

то, что указано в директиве `host` (с этой директивы начинаются секции в этом файле) — произвольная строка, которую вы теперь можете указывать и программе *ssh* и программе *git*.

если вы теперь добавите `~/.ssh/key1.pub` в первую из учётных записей (`acc1`), а `~/.ssh/key2.pub` — во вторую (`acc2`), то сразу можете и протестировать (только убедитесь предварительно, что каталог `~/.ssh` и его содержимое доступно для чтения и записи только вам — `chmod -R go= ~/.ssh`):

```
$ ssh -T gh-acc1
Hi acc1! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
$ ssh -T gh-acc2
Hi acc2! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

как видим, сервер отлично распознал обе учётные записи.

чтобы в дальнейшем использовать эту адресацию с помощью программы *git*, надо просто заменять в url-ах строку `git@github.com` на соответствующую строку (которую вы указали в строке с директивой `host` выше).

например, для клонирования репозитория `git@github.com:dockerdemo/apache.git` от имени учётной записи `acc1`:

```
$ git clone gh-acc1:dockerdemo/apache.git
```

а от имени учётной записи `acc2`:

```
$ git clone gh-acc2:dockerdemo/apache.git
```

Answer (score 3):

git вызывает ssh для работы с хостами (мы говорим именно об ssh а не raw-git/https)
если ты настроил ssh/ключи для каждого хоста, который ты используешь в работе, то никаких проблем не будет

т.е. твоя основная задача не настраивать гит, а настроить ssh для твоих хостов
google://ssh-copy-id

после того как ты сможешь логиниться в нужные тебе хосты, просто настраиваешь гит:

`git remote add workstation ssh://example.com/home/%USERNAME%/PATH_TO_SOURCE%`

тебе помогут команды `git remote set-url` и git `remote add`

для работы с разными репозиториями, например - набери `git remote -v` - увидишь все сетевые(или локальные но в другом каталоге фс) репозитории

после того как ты добавишь кучу разных реп (после `git remote add...`,

ты можешь делать например:

- `git push workstation` (пушишь с ноута на домашний комп, например),
- `git pull origin` (твой форк с гитхаба, например),
- `git fetch && git merge upstream/master` (пулл и мердж с последней версией мастера твоего форка)

вот тут почти годный ответ по дебагу коннекта git+ssh https://stackoverflow.com/a/36038548/5006740

вместо `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git clone example` можно использовать `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git clone example`

`-vvv` - еще более подробный дебаг чем  `-v`

Comment: но если у меня 2 разных репозитория на разных аккаунтах, а ключ ssh только один? Или в данном случае нужно наплодить n ключей для n аккаунтов ?

Comment: ты можешь использовать один ключ для всех хостов (если все твои репы находятся на гитхабе, то тебе и придется один ключ использовать), но  если у тебя куча хостов, куда ты можешь ssh://, то лучше использовать разные ключи, так просто безопаснее.  мало ли кто ключ стырит и убьет все твои репы и твой комп и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: в случае с разными ключами, как гит доберется до моего ключа на локальной машине. (1 лежит в .ssh в корне, а куда второй,третий и тд)

Comment: в случае с разными ключами (и в любом случае при работе через ssh), гит обратится к ssh, ssh посмотрит, есть ли у него нужные ключи для данного хоста, если нет - ругнется (в линуксе .ssh/config прописываются правила работы со всеми хостами, но для гитхаба тебе хватит и одной записи, поскольку гитхаб - один хост)

Comment: ну вот эта пара привязана к профайлу гита и локальной машине, а если есть надобность использовать другой репозиторий из другого профайла, как гиту обратится к своей паре ключа , уже для другого профайла

Comment: в гите нет профайлов никаких!. в гите есть remotes, если удаленный сервер разрешит твоей машине доступ, то ты можешь пулить / пушить туда. гит смотрит на урл репозитория, пытается запушить через протокол ssh/http/rawGit он или получает отлуп или все успешно проходит.