# Как узнать куда закоммитилось?

Tags: git

У меня 2 аккаунта на git
Создал папку, в ней:

```
git init
git add*
git commit -m "New"
```

Как узнать в какой аккаунт и репозиторий закоммитилось?
P.S. Как сменить аккаунт и репозитория при необходимости?

Comment: закомитить в репозиторий в гите нельзя. Поэтому ответы ниже бессмысленны. В удаленный репозиторий можно только запушить (git push), а эту команду Вы не выполняли.

Comment: Да я понял, сделал ответ fatal: No remote repository specified. видимо ничего не выбрано

Comment: все Ваши репозитории полностью локальны, пока только Вы осознанно не добавите удаленный репозиторий и явно туда запушите.  Более того, Вы можете подключиться к нескольким серверам и пушить/пулить в все.

Comment: @KoVadim может, ответом опубликуете? )

Comment: @KoVadim у каждого аккаунта свой SSH ключ. Как добавить 2 или более ключа что бы иметь возможность делать пулл-реквесты в репозитории на разных аккаунтах?

Comment: Это тянет на отдельный вопрос

Comment: @KoVadim, на который уже [есть ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/529240/178576).

Comment: @KoVadim: git не требует наличия удалённых репозиториев. Локальный репозиторий может содержать полную историю—`git commit` записывает изменения в локальный репозиторий. Хотя, судя по комментариям, автора интересуют именно удалённые репозитории (что никак с текстом самого вопроса не связано).

Answer (score 3):

Пока не сделаешь `git push ...` оно не будет ни в каком аккаунте, а будет просто локально на твоей машине. Что добавить два или более репозитория в проект нужно воспользоваться командой `git remote add название_репо(origin) url_адрес` и потом можно выполнить команду `git push название_репо(origin) название_ветки`. Какой аккаунт добавлен можно посмотреть вот этой командой `git config --list` там высветится почта и имя. Если хочешь пушить в два репозитория сразу, то нужно давать разрешения другому акаунту в одном из активных аккаунтов.

`git remote -vv` - посмотреть репозиторий.

`git config --list` - посмотреть почту и имя пользователя.

`git remote add название_репо(origin) url_адрес` - добавить новый репозиторий.

`git remote set-url название_репо(origin) url_адрес` - сменить репозиторий.