# Как добавить ключ в Git?

Tags: windows, git

Есть аккаунт на github, в нём в разделе SSH keys есть ключ, установлен git под Windows в папку E:\git есть программа puttygen и самый главный вопрос как всем этим пользоваться?

Читал [доступ к нескольким удаленным репозиториям по открытым ключам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/529017/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC-ssh/529240#529240)
Но там вообще непонятно где они файлы key1 и key2 создают, что за команда ssh-keygen, которая у меня пишет "ssh-keygen" не является внутренней или внешней
командой
Читал https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/ но там тоже всё под Linux а в разделе под винду я так понял хэлп по официальному приложению

Comment: А Вы ssh-keygen запускаете из терминала, который шел вместе с Git for Windows, "Git Bash"?

Comment: @Miron Команды git я запускаю в установленной ConEmu консоли там же запускал и указанную команду. Что вы имеете ввиду под который шел вместе с Git for Windows, "Git Bash" потому что с Git же и из обычной консоли винды можно работать.

Comment: Можно и из обычной, но тогда у вас будет появляться: "не является внутренней или внешней командой" и много чего еще. При изучении Git лучше пользуйтесь Git Bash, будете меньше задавать вопросов тут, а когда уже поймете как работает Git - тогда можно экспериментировать с консолями и т.п. :)

Comment: настало время установить gnu/linux! переходите на сторону зла, у нас есть печеньки!

Comment: @Miron, в ваших комментариях, фактически, содержится ответ на вопрос. оформите его, пожалуйста, в виде полноценного ответа.

Comment: @Miron ок, я запускаю консоль Git Bash, что дальше делать? Разницы никакой пока не вижу, всё так же не работает ))

Comment: @alexander barakin нет там пока и намёка даже на метод решения вопроса

Comment: Вот как раз ssh-keygen и должен заработать в Git Bash, помимо него в Git Bach будут работать и некоторые другие команды из Unix: pwd, whish, ...