# Как настроить SSH-ключи к разным репозиториям на github.com?

Tags: git, github, ssh

Нужно делать push одновременно к разным репозиториям на гитхабе.

1. Запись в конфиге гита сайта:

```
[remote "all"]
        url = git@github.com:repo1.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/all/*
        pushurl = git@github.com:repo1.git
        pushurl = git@github.com:repo2.git
```

2. Запись в конфиге .ssh (~/.ssh/config):

```
    Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key1_rsa

    Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key2_rsa
```

3. В обоих репозиториях лежат соответствующие публичные ключи.
4. Делаю

```
    sergey@debian:~/www/site$ git push all master
    Enter passphrase for key '/home/sergey/.ssh/key1_rsa': 
    Everything up-to-date
    Enter passphrase for key '/home/sergey/.ssh/key1_rsa': 
    ERROR: Repository not found.
    fatal: Не удалось прочитать из внешнего репозитория.

    Удостоверьтесь, что у вас есть необходимые права доступа
    и репозиторий существует.
```

Т.е., при первом пуше берет правильный ключ от первого репозитория, но при втором берет опять же его, хотя, нужно брать второй.

В конфиге .ssh запись сделал интуитивно, поэтому и не было уверенности, что заработает.

Comment: Посмотрите на предмет ssh-agent .https://habr.com/en/post/39116/

Comment: Думаю, проблема в понимании работы конфига `~/.ssh/config`: используется только первая запись и все. А вы хотите, чтобы циклически проходил? Решение - поправить второй адрес: `pushurl = git@repo2:repo2.git` - тут я добавил `repo2`. А в `~/.ssh/config` прописать этот `repo2` отдельно, вписав `HostName github.com` и ваш ключик. Надеюсь понятно объяснил

Comment: В принципе, то же самое, что я придумал: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419566/best-way-to-use-multiple-ssh-private-keys-on-one-client

Comment: @Total Pusher как же я добавлю туда "repo2", если этот весь url мне github выдает для коннекта к репозиторию? Насколько я понимаю, он статичен

Comment: Сергей, `~/.ssh/config` позволяет использовать алиасы. Я захожу на свой сервак так: `ssh vds`. В конфиге есть строчка `Host vds User **** HostName mysite.ru`. Поэтому мы просто делаем трюк: в репо меняем домен на алиас, а в `~/.ssh/config` вписываем его.

Comment: @Total Pusher вроде все сделал, но "ssh: Could not resolve hostname repo2: Temporary failure in name resolution"

Comment: `HostName github.com` вписан? Что выводит если вбить `ssh repo2`?

Comment: @Total Pusher, о, получилось! Спасибо!

Comment: И конкретно для гитхаба есть еще один трюк. Можно вписать `repo1.github.com`, `repo2.github.com` а в `~/.ssh/config` только указать соответствующий файл ключей и НЕ указывать HostName. Это будет работать так: записи в `~/.ssh/config` разные, поэтому тут ОК. Теперь нужно резолвить домен. У гитхаба есть NS запись со звездочкой (`dig "*.github.com"`), поэтому даже не существующий домен будет резолвен. Поэтому и не надо вписывать HostName. Это работает для всех репо, где в DNS есть звездочка для домена

Comment: Does this answer your question? [доступ к нескольким удаленным репозиториям по открытым ключам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/529017/%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bc)