# Как запушить проект на новый аккаунт на github?

Tags: git, github, cmd

Пользовался всё время одним и тем же аккаунтом на github'е. Создавал в нём репозитории и пушил без проблем все изменения в них. Сейчас пришлось создать ещё один аккаунт, зарегистрированный на другой e-mail, чтобы некоторые приложения пушить туда.
При попытке запушить изменения в новый аккаунт выдаёт такую ошибку:
remote: Permission to NewAccount/TestApp.git denied to PreviousAccount.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/NewAccount/TestApp.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему:
Как переключаться в командной строке между этими двумя аккаунтами (часть приложений пушить в один, остальные-во второй)?

Comment: а вы настроили SSH ключи?

Comment: настало время переходить от протокола http к протоколу ssh: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/529017/178576