# Как сделать отдельный ключ для каждого репозитория?

Tags: git

Я знаю что через конфиг можно указать файл ключ:

```
Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_project
```

Но он будет общим для всех. А я хочу отдельный для каждого. У github уже есть возможность указать deploy key для каждого репозитория. Вопрос в том как это настроить на сервере.

Comment: Что-то я не могу понять смысла этого действия. При чём тут сервер?

Comment: @AlexeyTen а я не могу понять что непонятно. Вроде объяснил вопрос.

Comment: Вы хотите пушить в каждый свой репозиторий с отдельным ключом? Или вы хотите пуллить на одном сервере из разных репозиториев с разными ключами?

Comment: @AlexeyTen второе

Comment: Тогда наверное проще использовать [GIT_SSH_COMMAND](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITSSHCOMMANDcode) `GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i path/to/key' git pull`

Comment: @AlexeyTen знаю про этот способ, но представляете себе каждый раз это писать? Это же геморрой... Я получаю изменения по десять раз на дню, а то и чаще.

Comment: Ну положите в конфиг https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coresshCommand

Comment: В целом, если вы это делаете 10 раз на дню, то стоит задуматься об автоматизации

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [доступ к нескольким удаленным репозиториям по открытым ключам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/529017/%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bc)