# Как скопировать токен SSH keys в командную строку?

Tags: git, github, cmd, git-push, git-cmd

Командная строка, при использовании `GitHub` (а точнее, когда я пытаюсь выполнить `git push`) просит ввести логин и пароль. После того, как я это делаю, вылетает следующее:

```
Необработанное исключение: System.MissingMethodException: Метод не найден: "Void Microsoft.AzureRepos.AzureReposHostProvider..ctor(Microsoft.Git.CredentialManager.ICommandContext)".
       в Microsoft.Git.CredentialManager.Program.Main(String[] args)
    remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
    remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
    fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/NikolajTrenirovki/SpinnerAndroidKotlin.git/'
```

Пройдя по ссылке `https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently`можно узнать, что вместо пароля теперь нужно вводить токен. Проблема в том, что вариант ctrl c ctrl v в этом случае не работает, командная строка просто игнорирует вставку и выдаёт ту же ошибку (вручную я тоже вводить пытался, увы, с тем же результатом).

`Важное уточнение`: пытаюсь запушить изменения для репозитория, находящегося во втором моём аккаунте github, в cmd я авторизован через первый аккаунт (в соавторы первый аккаунт я добавил, раньше этого вполне хватало)

Comment: Эм, токен который там нужен не имеет никакого отношения к SSH. Что вы туда пытаетесь вставить?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, по ссылке написано следующее: "Клонирование с помощью SSH URL-адресов
URL-адреса SSH предоставляют доступ к репозиторию Git через SSH, безопасный протокол. Чтобы использовать эти URL-адреса, вы должны сгенерировать пару ключей SSH на своем компьютере и добавить открытый ключ в свою учетную запись на GitHub.com . Для получения дополнительной информации см. раздел "Подключение к GitHub с помощью SSH...

Comment: @AlexeyTen, ...Когда вы git clone, git fetch, git pull, или git pushдля удаленного репозитория используете URL-адреса SSH, вам будет предложено ввести пароль, и вы должны указать свою кодовую фразу ключа SSH. Для получения дополнительной информации см. раздел "Работа с парольными фразами ключа SSH"."

Comment: @AlexeyTen, хотя может быть я что-то не так понял, подскажите, пожалуйста, в таком случае, что туда нужно вводить

Comment: Если вы хотите перейти на SSH, то нужно менять адрес удалённого репозитория. Ну и ssh на своём компьютере настроить.

Comment: Устанавливаете SSH. Создаёте ключ. И записываете **публичный** на github в меню Settings / SSH and GPG keys / new SSH key .

Comment: @AlexGlebe, SSH-ключ у меня есть, проблема в том, что я не могу вставить его в командную строку, когда она запрашивает пароль

Comment: подробнее надо показывать проблему, какие команды делаете, зарегистрировали-ли на сайте свой публичный ключ, какая программа работает с ключами ... я вряд-ли помогу, шорохаюсь в линуксе.

Comment: `git remote remove старое_подключение` и потом `git remote add SSH_подключение`

Comment: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/529017/178576)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ключ SSH работает по ssh, в описании ошибки видно что у Вас протокол https. Поменяйте ссылку на репо в формате `git@github.com:user/project.git`
через

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:NikolajTrenirovki/SpinnerAndroidKotlin.git
```

Для https используется другой тип ключей https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token . Потом включаешь хранение паролей `git config --global credential.helper store` и используй аксес токен вместо пароля. П.С. звездочки не рисуются при вводе -  вставляй вслепую.

Comment: премного благодарен!