# Git ошибка fatal: HTTP request failed

Tags: git, bitbucket

помогитте решить проблему с гитом 
гит работал корректно но со вчерашенго дня начались проблемы 
при команде на сервере git pull выбивает ошибку

**error:  while accessing https://NAME@bitbucket.org/Powinteh/MYPROJECT.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed**

локально тоже сломался но пишет другую ошибку

**Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.**

**Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.**

вроде в гугле есть похожие проблемы но перепробовал все варианты ничего не помогает

подскажите как поправить эту проблему или почему сломался гит не совсем пойму ?

Comment: золотое правило: во всех непонятных случаях при использовании «git поверх http» перейдите наконец на «[git поверх ssh](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html)».

Comment: я пробовал перейти на ssh делаю git clone git@bitbucket.org:Powinteh/MYPROJECT.git 
ошибка 
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
снова publickey мешает

Comment: в стопицотмильённый раз: так убедитесь, что на сайте вы разрешили использования публичной части именно того ключа, с которым пытаетесь подключаться.

Comment: . – alexander barakin  подскажите как это можно проверить или как правильно посмотреть ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/422636/178576